# Passing elements of String as a regex in scala

Tags: scala

### I extracted the required characters into scala string separated by a new line character ,I need to pass each of them to a regex one after the another and subsequently extract the 4th line after the matched regex in a loop.

Extracted String:

```
 CONFNO==0 conflegNO=0
 CONFNO==1 conflegNO=1
```

I/p Data:

```
Mar 28 07:29:44.385236   CONFNO==0 conflegNO=0
Mar 28 07:29:44.385248 conf Add port= 59224
Mar 28 07:29:44.385260 confAddLeg(): TX_RX_ENABLED
Mar 28 07:29:44.385272 confAddLeg(): confRm = 0 flags = 0x4000002040022, 
mcu_flags = 0x0
Mar 28 07:29:44.385286 mcuSendMsg() msg.type=0x07-MCU_InsertLeg  seqNo=0 
ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=127 incarnation_no=0 duration=0 rxCodec=2 
rxPT=8 txCodec=2 txPT=8
Mar 28 07:29:44.385236   CONFNO==1 conflegNO=1
Mar 28 07:29:44.385248 conf Add port= 59224
Mar 28 07:29:44.385260 confAddLeg(): TX_RX_ENABLED
Mar 28 07:29:44.385272 confAddLeg(): confRm = 0 flags = 0x4000002040022, 
mcu_flags = 0x0
Mar 28 07:29:44.385294 mcuSendMsg() msg.type=0x07-MCU_InsertLeg  seqNo=0 
ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=127 incarnation_no=0 duration=0 rxCodec=2 
rxPT=8 txCodec=2 txPT=8
```

Expected o/p:

```
Mar 28 07:29:44.385286 mcuSendMsg() msg.type=0x07-MCU_InsertLeg  seqNo=0 
ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=127 incarnation_no=0 duration=0 rxCodec=2 
rxPT=8 txCodec=2 txPT=8
Mar 28 07:29:44.385294 mcuSendMsg() msg.type=0x07-MCU_InsertLeg  seqNo=0 
ctlLegNo=0 confNo=0 legNo=0 digit=127 incarnation_no=0 duration=0 rxCodec=2 
rxPT=8 txCodec=2 txPT=8
```

Algo :

`take 1st line from the extracted string , use it as a regex and match this in the file and then form that point extract the 4th line  matched expression . Repeat it for all the elements in string.`

I am basically confused on how to pass regex elements as a loop and then extract them one by one

`This is what i have tried so far :`

```
 val regex44 =("CONFNO[A-Z]==[0-9]|conflegNO=[0-9]").r 

 val ll =  for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
      regex44.findFirstIn(line) match {
                                    case Some(text) => (strList5 += line + "\n")
                                      case None => null
                                          }}
                                   strList5.mkString
```

So , i Have successfully extracted them into a string `CONFNO==0 conflegNO=0
 CONFNO==1 conflegNO=1`but now How to reuse them into another regex one after the another to extract the next 4th line ahead of each of them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In general, you'll have to show some example of what you've tried to solve the problem and then ask about specific issues.

Comment: @Dennis Hunziker  HI , I added the code.

Comment: your regex includes `CONFNO[A-Z]==[0-9]`. Is the `[A-Z]` intentional? As is, it won't match `CONFNO==0` for example

Comment: @joelb [A-Z] is for matching only caps characters , It matches CONFNO==0 . If I wont add [A-Z] then it will match confno==0 also.

Comment: that is true it will only match caps characters, but it expects exactly one caps character after `CONFNO`, which isn't present in `CONFNO==0`. See `"CONFNO[A-Z]==0".r.findFirstMatchIn("CONFNO==0")`. Which part of the regex are you trying to ensure is caps?

Comment: @joelb Any idea on how to pass regex into a loop ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd probably solve this, without using any more complex regex logic though.

```
def findNthLine(n: Int, r: Regex): List[String] = {
   @tailrec
   def rec(lines: List[String], acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
      if (lines.isEmpty) acc
      else {
         r.findFirstIn(lines.head) match {
            case Some(_) if lines.size > n => rec(lines.drop(n), acc :+ lines(n))
            case _ => rec(lines.tail, acc)
         }
      }
   }
   rec(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toList, Nil)
}

val result = findNthLine(4, regex44)
```

Some explanations:

- Your regex is always the same, so this code recursively iterates through the lines and tries to find a match
- If a match is found: It drops n number of lines from the input and appends the n'th line to the accumulator (`case Some(_)`)
- If no match is found or less than n number of lines are available it ignores the current line and continues the recursion (`case _`)
- Finally, the recursion stops when there is no more input

Comment: Thanks a  lot Dennis , Can you please give a brief description about your logic. I just want to learn the implementation.

Comment: Done, I'd highly recommend the Scala courses on Coursera to get a better understanding of the language and it's features.